# How to tokenize values from a file and store it in a 2D array

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I have a textfile which contains something like this:
1|2|3|4|5|.......23|24|25

I need to read this file, tokenize the values and enter the values in a 2D array.

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++) 
{
    for (j=0; j<size; j++)
    {   
        board[i][j] = *buffer;
        buffer++;
    }
}
```

I need to tokenize the values using "|" as delim and enter the values into the 2D array... Please help. I know the above is not correct, pls help.

Comment: how do you determine the two dimensions? Why the tag `tictactoe`? Is it a homework?

Comment: It is a homework of writing an extended version of tictactoe..The entire game code is complete...but I need to use File I/O to store the game and later continue

Comment: Good. Adding the tag. Now about the dimensions...?

Comment: the 2 dimensions are based on the board size which is a user input. While saving the game, I save the size too so that I can reload the same board with the size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading data from file into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239689/reading-data-from-file-into-array)

Answer (score 0):

- Read the data from file in a string.
- Apply string tokenizer on your string and get the separate data.

  For tokenizing the string, take a look at [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html). It's great. Boost generally has some very cool string tools.
  Once you get separate data you can store it in 2-D array.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the whole file into a char * array. I'll assume that's what is in buffer and then use strtok to tokenize with "|".

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: I am trying to use strtok but how do I store the seperate data into a 2D format

Comment: how are determining the value "size" variable above? from the code you have provided it looks like the file contains data in row major order and you have the size stored somewhere.

Comment: initially the size is taken as input from the user..the game board is designed based on that.eg., size 5 draws a 5X5 board. Later when the game is saved, the size is also saved into a file and when the file is read, the board is again drawn on the same size. The prob is where I need to draw the board with the exact player marks before the game was saved.

Comment: how about this to save file   fprintf(file, "%d ", size);  for(int row = 0; row < size; ++row) for(int col = 0; col < size; ++col)  fprintf(file, "%d ", board[row][col]);  Now you can read back the file same way using fscanf.

Comment: Note that I'm using a space in "%d "